# IIS7 Custom Errror Handling Troubles for Classic ASP Website

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, error-handling

I recently upgraded a web server from IIS6 to IIS7 for a classic asp application and now experience a bizarre error.  In the IIS6 set up there was a custom 500-100 page that functioned properly by capturing errors and delivering an email with error code, error source and error type values.  That same structure was set up on the IIS7 machine but now the error emails contain no error information at all.  They all come through values such as 'NO SPECIFIC ERROR CODE', 'NO SPECIFIC ERROR DESCRIPTION', 'NO SPECIFIC ERROR SOURCE'.  Any one have some thoughts on why my custom error page cannot capture the error information?

Comment: Can you post your error handler script? I googled around and the values you're reporting don't have any hits which suggests there's something amiss with the script itself.

Comment: So the 'client connection test interval' property needed to be set to something higher than the default 3 seconds.  Now errors are capturing correctly.

Comment: Eaphis, please post your solution as an answer, then accept your answer, so we know that this is no longer an unanswered question.

Comment: Thanks Martha.  Done and Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the 'client connection test interval' property needed to be set to something higher than the default 3 seconds. Now errors are capturing correctly